# Are the blue marks on the face and necks of Cardassian females makeup or a tattoo?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Throughout the run of DS9, Cardassian females can often be seen with one or more of their neck-bones colored in blue or purple. An example is in the screenshot below. Same goes for the spoon-shaped area on the forehead. It's a neat little cultural quirk that was never explained on the show.

**Is this coloring permanent (ie, a tattoo) and what does it signify? Or is it just the Cardassian version of wearing makeup?**

[image]

Comment: Same with the forehead-spoon

Comment: Maybe that part of a female Cardassian’s skin is blue or purple.

Comment: It seems to be an inconsistent feature, unlike the blueing of the forehead spoon

Comment: Could just be a common birthmark.

Comment: You might want to add the blue mark in the forehead ridge to this question since my answer addresses both

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Main Canon

It *appears* to be a cosmetic of some description. Not only do the blue marks appear inconsistently on different Cardassian females (ranging from highly visible to not at all), but we also see these marks appear and disappear on ***Garak***, a Cardassian male, which strongly suggests that they're temporary and cosmetic rather than physiological and permanent.

[image]
[image]

The make-up artist who designed the physical masks, Michael Westmore stated in a featurette that they were "*painted*", but it's not apparent whether he's talking about that from an in-universe perspective.

> "To give them [female Cardassians] something a little different, because at the beginning we thought 'How you gonna tell them apart if they're not wearing a dress', was to take and paint the center of their spoons at the center of their forehead, to paint it blue. And then we picked out the second or third rung down on their neckpiece and that was also painted blue. So all female Cardassians always had those blue markings."
>
> <sub><sup>DS9: Season 2 - special features: Make up and costumes</sup></sub>

---

### EU Canon

In the novel [*Terok Nor: Dawn of the Eagles*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Eagles), Quark offers us the benefit of his experience regarding Cardassian women. The blue mark on the forehead (and presumably the marks on the collarbone) are makeup.

> Women were a different matter. Quark came up from the cellar after the
> lunch rush one fine, lucrative day to find that there was a new face
> in his establishment, a female face. He’d seen Cardassian women
> before, but they were always either uniformed or accompanied by a
> male. This woman was neither. She was dressed in a long, green
> gown—not a scientist or a soldier, and apparently nobody’s wife,
> either. **The dimple in her forehead was painted bright blue, something
> that Quark was reasonably certain indicated that she was not married.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Terok Nor: Dawn of the Eagles](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Eagles)</sup></sub>

Comment: Interesting how visibly different Garak's two different prosthetics are. The bony structures around the eyes and leading up the forehead are quite a bit different.

Comment: @FreeMan - His are more expensive and reusable. The others are made of cheaper material